# What are appropriate objects of 制作?

Tags: word-choice, usage

My dictionary, along with many websites I've checked translates 制作 as:

- to make
- to manufacture

What sorts of things may I 制作?

The second definition of "manufacture" leads me to believe that, for example, "I made new flash cards." /「我制作了新的词卡。」, is too small-scale a thing to be 制作'ed. I haven't found any examples at [Chinese-Tools](http://www.chinese-tools.com/) or [Mandarin Tools](http://www.mandarintools.com/cgi-bin/wordlook.pl) or in my dictionary.

Comment: `我制作了新的词卡` is OK. `制作` doesn't specially mean "large-scale manufacture" in Chinese. But, `制造` does.

Comment: Anything that involves labor, requires a series of steps or procedures and an attention to details. Example, a movie, a cake, a greeting card, toys.

Comment: The object of 制作 is not necessarily large-scale thing. "制作了一张单词卡" is perfectly OK.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow: "requires ... **an attention to details**" is really important. For example, some large-scale thing cannot be `制作`-ed, it will sound very weird -- native speakers don't say `制作轮船/客机/楼房`.

Comment: @Stan, yes, I know that. Have added an answer below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After going through a few online examples, I think this is what **制作** actually means:

To make something physically that requires a level of skill or artistry, such as, a movie, a cake, a greeting card or a toy. Example:

> 韩国制作巨型巧克力高跟鞋迎接情人节 (South Korea has made a gigantic pair of chocolate stilettos to welcome Valentine's Day)

Since **制造** is also mentioned, to provide disambiguation, 制造 means to manufacture or mass-produce something (both physical and non-physical). Example:

> 这AK-47是前苏联制造的 (This AK-47 was made in the former USSR)
>   制造垃圾 (churning out rubbish)
>   制造欢乐气氛 (creating a joyous atmosphere)

To build or construct something, usually big, we can use the word **建造**. For example:

> 建造楼房 (construct a building)
>   建造卫星导航系统 (build a satellite navigation system)

Comment: Thanks for expanding upon the other answer. The additional commentary on similar words has helpfully widened my vocabulary!

Comment: You are welcome, glad to know that :)

Answer (score 1):

Look here for a very full list of examples: http://www.nciku.com/search/zh/detail/%E5%88%B6%E4%BD%9C/1319727

`制作` is comparable to the English word `to make`, as you can 制作 anything from cake to advertisements.

Comment: This sentence on that webpage fails in dividing phrases: 内阁 **制作** 为一种政治体制，有它一定的合理性。 `内阁制(度)` should be one phrase, "cabinet system".

Comment: Since the website just searches through all the example sentences for any matches to the given characters, this can happen a lot, but with so many examples, it's still useful.

Comment: That's right :) I just put a warning for the possible misleading. It's still a wonderful site.